# What is the use of Android .rc files

Tags: android, linux, rc

What is the use of .rc files in Android framework. I see a lot of files what is there purpose. Also I have a little knowledge about linux but I see commands like

```
mkdir /dirName 0777 abc def
```

what does that mean. If I run this command on GNU-Linux it creates folder named dirName, 0777, abc and def. I know its like giving permissions while creating directory also abc and def are somewhat like owner or root, but not sure.
Does commands in .rc file runs different in Linux normal kernel and in Android linux kernel.
Is there any link or online material to study to learn the same that how can we write and use .rc files in Android.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Thanks for the reply. I already knew .rc files contains instructions for the compiler and what is the purpose of .rc files.
([Definition of .rc file](http://linux.about.com/cs/linux101/g/rcfile.htm)).

I was more concerned about its usage with context of Android and how commands are used. After searching a lot I finally found a link explaining basics of it ([Android INIT Language](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_system_core/blob/master/init/README.md)).

As in my question I asked how mkdir command usage is different in android .rc file its well explaind in readme file in [this link](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_system_core/blob/master/init/README.md).

Thanks again.

Comment: Your Android INIT Language link is broken

Answer (score 0):

.rc files contain instructions for the compiler.

This [source](http://www.ehow.com/facts_5697167_file-extension-rc_.html) explains it so much better.  [Marakana](http://marakana.com/static/courseware/android/internals/index.html) deals a little bit with GNU command line and things of that nature.  I am not sure if I answered your question exactly how you wanted, but hopefully this points you in the right direction.